# Как отправить фото с интернета aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

раньше я использовал код

```
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(f'photo/vk.png', 'rb'), caption=f'<b>Введите ссылку на страницу:</b>', parse_mode='html')
```

Но сейчас я хочу оптимизировать память, и меня заинтересовал вопрос, как отправить фото с интернета
Что бы файл не скачивать и не хранить локально
Может как то через get() и content

Comment: await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo='ваша ссылка на картинку')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo='ссылка на картинку')
```

За подробностями в документацию

Answer (score 0):

в аргумент photo передай url картинки, в базе данных можешь хранить в виде url